# How to sum up Array values

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

having issues with arrays sum and return. Algorithm is also having issues with a single value array. Idea is to sum up numbers and form a new array until there's only one value left. For example Array [1,2,3,2] turns into [3,5,5], [8,10] and finally [18]. What is the best way to sum up array values and return it?

```
public class Arraytest {

int count(int[] t) {

    if (t.length > 1) {
        int[] tt = new int[t.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length - 1; i++) {
            tt[i] += t[i] + t[i + 1];
            System.out.println(tt[i]);
        }
        count(tt);
    }
    return 0;
}

}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Arraytest at = new Arraytest();
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5})); // 48
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {2})); // 2
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {7,1,1,3,8,2,9,5,4,2})); // 2538
}}
```

Comment: You're having an issue with a single value array because you skip all the code if it's a single-element array. Seems like that'd cause an issue at the end, too; you should return that single element since it's the answer.

Comment: That's what my JS version got; seems much righter. In any case, you're not returning anything other than zero, ever. That seems wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static int count(int[] t) {
    if(t.length == 1)
        return t[0];
    else if (t.length > 1) {
        int[] tt = new int[t.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length - 1; i++)
            tt[i] += t[i] + t[i + 1];
        return count(tt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the end you always returned zero instead of returning the last int in the array

Comment: Instead of doing their homework for them perhaps it would be more educational to *help* them instead of just handing them an answer on a plate.

Comment: I was going too, just give me some time instead of writing a comment the second i post this ^^

Comment: Another approach would be to post only complete answers.

Answer (score 0):

Working Code:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Main t = new Main();
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5})[0]); // 48
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {2})[0]); // 2
System.out.println(t.count(new int[] {7,1,1,3,8,2,9,5,4,2})[0]); // 323
}
static int[] count(int[] t) {
if(t.length == 1)
    return t;
else if (t.length > 1) {
    int[] tt = new int[t.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length - 1; i++) {
        tt[i] += t[i] + t[i + 1];
    }
    return count(tt);
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO this is worse than the already-accepted answer (and formatted worse as well). It also doesn't follow the contract of the original code.